# What is the role of "throws exeption" in method definition in Java?

Tags: java

Some methods are deciared this way: `public int myMethod() throws Exception {` (return an int or throw Exception if method fails). However, stub methods in NetBeans look like

```
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        if(false){ //this branch is never used
                int a = getInt();
        }
    }

    private static int getInt() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

This stub doesn't attempt to return an `int`. Instead it `throws exception` right away. Yet, IDE accepts it as a valid syntax. The program compiles and runs.

Is `throw new UnsupportedOperationException` considered a valid return for any return type?
What is the role of `throws Exception` in the definition of a Java method?

Comment: You may want to search more about checked and unchecked exceptions. For instance, see [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) on StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the role of “throws exeption”

It's used for *checked exceptions*.

The idea is, if you write code to call a function that `throws FoobarException`, then the compiler will force you to either handle the exception, or to add the same `throws FoobarException` declaration to the function that you are writing.

It's a way to make sure that nobody will forget that a `FoobarException` might be thrown.

> This stub doesn't attempt to return an int. Instead it throws exception right away. Yet, IDE accepts it as a valid syntax. The program compiles and runs.

Checked exceptions turn out not to be as popular as the language designers had hoped.  In fact, they anticipated that when they created a whole category of *unchecked* exceptions.

`UnsupportedOperationException` is an unchecked exception.  Unchecked exceptions work exactly the same as checked exceptions.  The only difference is that you are not required to declare the exception when you write a method that could throw it.  Every exception that inherits from `java.lang.RuntimeException` is unchecked.

The idea is, you're supposed to use checked exceptions for conditions that your program ought to handle in some graceful way (e.g., inform the user about a file-not-found instead of just crashing), and only use unchecked for exceptions that "can't possibly happen" unless your program is broken.

> Is throw new UnsupportedOperationException considered a valid return for any return type?

No, it's not a "return", it's an exception.  The compiler doesn't mind that your method never returns an `int`, because the compiler can tell that your method never returns at all.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say much in the Javadocs about how this is implemented in the compiler, nor does it for the equivalent `NotImplementedException` in C#.

However, it wouldn't surprise me if the compiler's static code analysis went something like this:  *an exception is thrown unconditionally before `return` is called, so there's no need to check the return type.*

When you think about it, this does make sense.  The only reason these exceptions exist is to allow you to stub out a method for later implementation; it would be quite inconvenient if you couldn't specify a return type.

It would be easy enough to find out if the compiler treats this particular exception as a special case.  Just change it to some other exception, and see if the compiler complains.